# I Need modify countdown in jQuery

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I want to modify my jQuery code please help. this is countdown timer start from 30 and end on 0 and then its stop.

I want when my countdown on 0 then its start again from 30. I want randomly countdown from 30 to 0 and then start 30 to 0.

```
// Random Countdown Timer Script, by http://ctrtard.com

var timer;

function startCount() {
    timer = setInterval(count, 1000); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}

function count() {
    var rand_no = Math.ceil(1 * Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
    var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
    if (newNumber > 0) {
        el.innerHTML = newNumber;
    } else {
        el.innerHTML = "Sold Out"; // This message is displayed when the counter reaches zero.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function count() {
    var rand_no = Math.ceil(1 * Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
    var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
    if (newNumber > 0) {
        el.innerHTML = newNumber;
    } else {
        setElemVal(el , 30);
        count();   
    }
}

function setElemVal(el , val) {
    el.innerHTML = '';
    el.innerHTML = val;
}
```

Just add another function to reset the value and change the `else` condition.

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gkcubt32/)**

Comment: i check this code and its not work :( when i put this code replace on old my countdown timer stop on 30 its not running as i want

Comment: @RanaFaisal you can press tick mark , if this solved your problem :)

Comment: No probs .. happy to help